# Flask-SQLAlchemy join and get maximal by timestamp

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i have a 3 models

```py
    class A(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'table_a'
     id = ...  
     title = ...
     timestamp = ... # CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    
    
    class B(Base):
      __tablename__ = 'table_b'
      id = ...        # primary
      timestamp = ... # CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    
      a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table_a')) # references to A model
    
    
    class C(Base):
      __tablename__ = 'table_c'
      id = ...              # primary
      timestamp = ...       # CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    
      b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table_b')) # references to B model
```

Example table

```
table_a
id    timestamp 
1     2020-01-01 00:00:01
2     2020-07-01 12:14:12
etc...
```

```
table_b
id    a_id   timestamp 
1     1       2020-05-04 00:00:01
2     1       2020-07-01 12:14:12
3     2       2020-07-01 12:14:12
etc...
```

```
table_c
id    b_id   timestamp 
1     1       2020-06-04 00:12:01
2     2       2020-08-01 11:14:12
3     2       2020-11-01 12:14:12
etc...
```

So i need to implement query to fetch rows for every A which has latest B by timestamp (or id) and for this B i need to fetch latest C by timestamp

Example for A with id = 1 i will have

A.id = 1, B.id = 2 , C.id = 3

I know how to get maximal by timestamp using subqueries

```
        sub_c = db.session.query(
            C.b_id,
            func.max(C.timestamp).label('c_max_tmstmp')
        ).group_by(C.b_id).subquery('c_query')

        sub_b = db.session.query(
            B.a_id,
            func.max(B.id).label('max_id')
        ).group_by(B.a_id).subquery('b_query')
```

But i dont understand how to combine them with A

Answer (score 0):

i have tried next solution, but i'm not sure if it is really correct or if there are any optimizations

```
        query = (db.session
            .query(A, B, C)
            .join(sub_b)
            .filter(B.id == sub_b.c.max_id)
            .join(sub_c)
            .filter(
                and_(
                    C.b_id == sub_b.c.max_id,
                    C.timestamp == sub_c.c.max_timestamp
                )
            )
        )
```